# Extract Year from the adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel, extract

I have 4 columns in use I (File_Date), J(File_Year), K(Resol_Date), L(Resol_Year) So far, I have the following code that doesn't work..

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets(3).FormulaR1C1 = "=YEAR(RC[-1])"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"""",YEAR(RC[-1]))"
Range("J2").Select
```

Dates are already given so all I have to do is extract years from Column I to Column I , from Column K to Column L starting from row 2 to the lastrow which is predetermined by a different procedure

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells

lastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show us some sample data, along with something that you have tried and then we can help.

Comment: Why are you asking for a macro/vba, when a very simple Excel formula will do the job?

Comment: I know that it can be done with a simple =year () formula but since the whole File_Date column is formatted as date when I pull a year it will extract weird year like '1905'. Also, I am trying to automate this due to its repetitive nature with more than 200 files. Thanks..

Comment: I have added a VBA solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a worksheet formula, no need for VBA.

In column J, enter the below formula, and copy down.

```
=YEAR(I:I)
```

**VBA CODE:**

to do this with VBA on **all rows** then try this:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long

lLastRow = Range("I" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("J1:J" & lLastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(I:I),"""",YEAR(I:I))"
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks and I am aware of that but due to its repetitive nature, I would like to have it as macro

Comment: @BLkrn: I have added a VBA solution that will work on all the rows as they are populated

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the entire code or just the statement for extracting the year? The following line should work if you integrate it into an existing macro.

```
activecell.value=Year(activecell.offset(0,-1).value)
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that only the active cells will use the code?

Comment: @BLkrn: Yes, so you need to apply that code to an entire range.. **or use a formula that you copy down**